# Is it fine to offer a left and a right navigation at the same time, when I have several menu items?

Tags: navigation, sidemenu

I am designing a dashboard for a supply chain company. Their web dashboard has several options on the top navigation. But I am designing the tablet version and I am thinking to go the conventional left hand side navigation. **Will it be a bad UX if I display navigation on both sides of the screen that is left and right together?** This way I can divide the menus without making a clutter. I am planning to make them collapsible.

Comment: Most decisions made about design derives from the context in which the problem for the user needs to be solved. It is just as likely that by splitting the navigation that you require the users to shift their focus from side-to-side, thereby reducing the efficiency that might be gained by decreasing the number of items that they have to scan to find what they are looking for. It really depends on the way that the menu items are designed and the rest of the information displayed on the dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

That seems like it could be confusing to the user, especially if each menu has a different set of functions per side. To cut down on clutter in the navigation pane you could let the user pin their most used functions to the top of the navigation pane or create a dynamic/or contextual section at the top of the navigation pane.

[image: Pinned Menu Mockup]
(Forgive the crude mockup.)